# vba excel - list files in folder where file created date matches week number and weekday name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to list all files in a folder where the file created date has a week number and weekday name that matches the values in cells H7 and N7.

For instance my folder contains the following files:

```
1.PDF (Created 16/12/2016)
2.PDF (Created 01/12/2016)
3.PDF (Created 16/12/2016)
```

My cell H7 contains the week number 50 (which 15th December would fall under).

My cell N7 contains the weekday Friday (which would match the 16th december).

The code i am using is below:

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer



'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
If Dir("G:\STOCK\(3) Promotions\Allocations\" & Range("T7").Value & "\" & client, vbDirectory) <> "" Then


Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("G:\STOCK\(3) Promotions\Allocations\" & Range("T7").Value & "\")




'Utilize Adv Day = False
If Range("N7").Value <> "" Then


i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files


If DatePart("ww", objFile.DateCreated, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = Range("H7").Value And WeekdayName(Weekday(objFile.DateCreated)) = Range("N7").Value Then


'print file PG
    Cells(i + 12, 1) = Range("T7").Value
    'print file Month
    Cells(i + 12, 5) = Range("H7").Value

    'print file Year
    Cells(i + 12, 9) = Range("B7").Value

    'print file name
    Cells(i + 12, 13) = objFile.Name

    'print file path
    Cells(i + 12, 18) = "=hyperlink(""" & objFile.Path & """)"

    i = i + 1
    End If

Next objFile

Else

MsgBox "No Results Found."

End If

End If

End Sub
```

The code doesn't seem to work correctly, if i put in Saturday into cell N7 then it lists the files with friday's date.

Also the code is listing all files and not just those files with Friday's date.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wish I had enough points to comment, but maybe this will be helpful.

The code worked when I used it, just changing the target folder to a folder on my computer.

Are you trying to use the date the file was created or the date it was modified? This code is looking only at the created date.

Note that the day-of-week name is case sensitive, so you might want to compare upper-case or lower-case versions of the day.